# Can I use a TP-link TD-W8151N as a wireless repeater?

Tags: wireless-networking, wifi-configuration

I have a Asus RT-N10E that I am using with a wimax connection that is giving me a Wi-Fi network. I just installed a Yagi antenna in my neighbors house but the signal strength is extremely low (no direct line of sight). Since I have a TP-link TD-W8151N on hand; I was wondering if I could set this up as a wireless repeater in order to give me line of sight to the Yagi?

Can I set up my TP-link TD-W8151N as a wireless repeater or extender, if so how?

Comment: The easiest way to get an answer is to log into the administration interface. Do you know how ?

Comment: yeah i know how...

Comment: If you can use it as a repeater there will be an option to search for access points, and then to bind your wireless router as a repeater for it. Just try it.

Comment: Set up WDS as explained in [this article](http://www.tp-link.com/lk/article/?faqid=327).